# Firebase/Crashlytics Dashboard not showing any test crashes for android

Tags: android, ios, react-native, crashlytics, firebase-crash-reporting

### I can't understand why it's not showing into Firebase Crashlytics Dashboard ,when i'm trying to link this packages manually i'm getting the error about the duplication. Else i trying to change dependencies for it but i have still have this issue.But in iOS it works good and show me non-fatal errors.

On Android when i am creating custom errors for testing into Firebase Crashlytics dashboard doesn't show me any types of crashes (look the pic. below)

[image]

Here i am paste the "maven{url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'}" into buildscript > repositories Else i'm past the needed classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.1' into buildscript > dependencies block

```
My code integration was so  android/build.gradle
```

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {        
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.1'
    }
}            
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
}
```

---

Here i'm paste the apply plugin: 'io.fabric' and implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'

```
android/app/build.gradle
```

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "io.fabric"

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Into package.json i have installed last version of packages

```
package.json
```

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "@react-native-firebase/app": "^6.2.0",
        "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^6.2.0"
    }
}
```

> NOTE : I don't link manually (as i understood i don't need to do it because it is doing automatically "react-native auto-linking")

```
Here is my 'index.js' file
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import crashlytics from '@react-native-firebase/crashlytics';

class App extends Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        // Here is my custom errors
        // But it's now showing in dashboard
        // But in iOS it works good
        crashlytics().recordError(new Error('For test'));
        crashlytics().log('For test');
    }
    render () {
       return (
           <View>
              <Text>Test</Text>
           </View>
       )
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: please write the question in a better method, so that others can understand it better

Comment: testing production or developement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are running analytics in development mode.

In Android craslytics are send in production mode only.

Comment: Sorry. But how can i debug without development mode ?

Comment: react-native run-android --variant=release